# Using an Array on components Astro

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I am having problems to use the map on to the components

1. New installation (npm create astro@latest), the basic version, with no typescript (I do not know if its necessary)

src/components/Card.astro

```
---
export interface Props {

    items: Array<string>;
}

const { items } = Astro.props as Props;
---

<ol>
 {items.map((item) => (
  <li>{item}</li>
 ))}
</ol>
```

src/pages/index.Astro

```
import Card from '../components/Card.astro';
---
<Card
 items=["a"]
/>
```

Error: ERROR: Expected "}" but found "a"

In advance thanks

Comment: Please add the complete error stack to your question (not just the error message itself)!

Answer (score 6):

Use `<Card items={["a"]} />` because without curly braces astro thinks you are writing html code.